# Is possible to use new plugins of Capacitor on old apps developed in Cordova?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor-plugin

I'm starting as a mobile trainee developer in a company, and there is an app developed in Cordova and probably Ionic 2, I need to create a feature that uses a capacitor plugin (records an audio and create a base64 code to sent to API), the issue happens right after installing the plugin and calling "ionic serve", I get the error:

error TS1005: '=' expected.  1 import type { VoiceRecorderPlugin } from './definitions';
As check for imports, I did for page.ts and module.ts.

I tried to update the app to Capacitor, but unfortunately this is a complex app, and there are lots of errors when I try it.
The options for now is use native plugins, and in the worst case refactor all the app.

Have you guys faced it before? Is possible to use new plugins to old apps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Step 1. Update all of the code to work with latest Ionic/Angular. Once you have experienced that pain you can move on to step2....the MUCH more painful task of migrating to Capacitor and ensuring your legacy Cordova plugins play nice with your newer Capacitor plugins. Without upgrading first you will not get past the build process.

Comment: Hello E. Maggini
Thanks for your answer, that was what I was trying to avoid for now due to being necessary to have this feature working before remaking all the app. But if this is the case, it is what it is.
Best regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.